# Async Request in (Scala) Play "Hangs"

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I've written an application (Scala) Play and when I run it on my local machine, it works exactly as I expect.  The method that I'm working on (there may be others with this issue, I haven't checked extensively) is a method triggered by a POST request.  It returns an Async object because the evaluation done by the method returns a Future.

But this method behaves quite differently when I deploy it.  I've been chasing this down all day, but I've gotten to the point where I have no explanation for what is going on.

The method looks something like this:

```
  def add = Action(parse.json) { request =>
    Async {
      val req = request.body.asOpt[TaskRequest] map { r =>
        val job = createJob(r)
        submitJob(job, r)
        job map { ij =>
          allowOrigin(Created(ij).withHeaders("Location" -> routes.Jobs.read(ij._id.stringify).url));
        }
      }
      req.get
    }
  }
```

Overall, this is pretty simple.  The `createJob` method returns a `Future[Job]`.  The `submitJob` call is a kind of "fire and forget" call to trigger some background stuff (that I'm not interested in waiting for).  I then process the `job` result to produce a `Result` object when the `job` has been **created**.

All this works as I described above on my local machine.  But when I deploy this, something really odd happens.  That `submitJob` call triggers a long running computation.  As I said, I'm not interested in waiting for it which is why I don't even use the `Future` that it returns anywhere.

But here's the odd part...on my development machine, the response from my POST request (which directly calls add) comes back as soon as the job is created.  But on the deployment machine, I only get a response after the `submitJob` task is completed!  In other words, I've got this `req` as a `Future` that is seemingly completely unrelated to that `submitJob` call (it certainly doesn't depend on its outcome), but in the deployment environment, `Async` block won't return until `submitJob` is complete (even though `req` is fulfilled almost immediately).

What the heck is going on here?  I've put `println` statements all through the code.  It definitely gets past that `req.get` call almost immediately.  But the overall (HTTP) response definitely waits until `submitJob` is done.  Does `Async` somehow know about the `submitJob` call?  IF so, why does it behave differently on two different machines?

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the deployment machine under your control? Are you able to get stack dump from both machines and compare?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. There is no stack trace here because there is no exception. If I wanted to try and dump the stack (without an exception), I'm not sure how I would do that or where?

Comment: Sorry I meant a thread dump. If you download a tool like http://visualvm.java.net/ or create a thread dump by sending SIGQUIT to the process or CTRL-BREAK in Windows, then you can see the stack calls of all your threads in the JVM. It is helpful for finding the root cause.

Comment: My suspicions is that this has something to do with some underlying thread pool not having enough threads or something.  Any ideas on a simple way to check this?  I tried putting blocking { ... } around the submitJob call to spawn an extra thread somehow, but that didn't work (no surprise...since it doesn't actually block).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.  Oh what a pain that was.  The issue was that my "fire and forget" task was a long running task.  But the thread pool size on the deployment machine ended up being smaller than my development machine.  As a result, this long running task dropped in the thread pool and clogged it up.  So the processing of the `AsyncResult` was presumably preempted by the long running calculation (it was actually blocking on a result from a long running calculation, but the bottom line is that it blocked).

After reading a really nice explanation of futures in Scala 2.10 by Heather Miller, I noticed the `blocking` construct that can be used to temporarily expand the size of the thread pool for a single future.  I wrapped my blocking code with a `blocking` call and that did the trick.  Presumably, this allocated an additional temporary worker to handle my blocking call and, as a result, the `AsyncResult` stuff got processed in a timely manner.

(Note, wrapping the `submitJob` call was useless because that, itself, didn't block.  What I had to do was go into the `submitJob` call and find the place where the actual blocking was and wrap that.)

Answer (score 4):

Though you have figured out, but there is an another alternative. This normally happens when you use say scala's default ThreadPool i.e. `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global`. It uses a `newFixedSizeThreadPool` with size as `number of cores` of machine.

An alternative would be to use your own `ExecutionContext` with the future calls above. i.e. in your above code, add this line:

```
implicit val exec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool())
```

All your `future` calls will then use the above `ExecutionContext`.

Comment: An excellent point.  I can understand all the "implicit" voodoo here because it would be a pain to have to explicitly specify these things each time you represented a future.  But it is also nice to know how to explicitly define an alternative implicit context.  Thanks.